How to require manual approval for ssh logins
I would like to require a manual approval (by means of physical access, like GUI or framebuffer console) from the device being ssh'd to before letting in any connections. Presumably it would need to generate some unique token to ensure that the incoming connection is the one that I'm intending to allow. Is there any PAM module or other way to implement this on Linux?
My use case is being able to quickly create tunnels between devices (to which I have physical access) for occasional debugging or admin actions without weakening overall network security with additional ssh keys or passwords.

You could write a PAM module that does this. You might be able to fudge a solution using pam_exec. I think a more effective solution would be to require ssh keys + a two factor code.

What about allowing on Firewall level only certain IP to ssh and drop requests from extern?

Does this involve exactly one user? In other words, shall it work only for a certain user logging in via SSH and the approving user is the same user already logged in?

Additional (separate for each machine) SSH keys can only strengthen the security. Moreover, like @larsks mentioned, SSH keys are a better solution from the security standpoint than passwords. Other than that, disable root logins and set up a firewall to limit the use of SSH. Administration should not be done remotely if possible. If really needed, use something like sudo or doas on the remote machine itself, rather than logging directly as root from the remote machine.

@Vilinkameni and planetmaker : the point is that I want these login permissions to be temporary, so that once I'm done there are no keys lingering around and if either machine is compromised it doesn't affect the other. Of course, this can be done manually by generating a key, copying it somehow and deleting afterwards, but that's kind of a roundabout way of doing it, since I only want one-off connections.

For now I ended up going with the simplest solution - writing a custom shell (similar to how git-shell can be used to provide restricted access). The shell sends a message to local daemon and waits for approval with a short timeout. If approval is given, it exec's /bin/sh as usual.

Have you disabled chsh? Have you changed `/etc/shells? What if (l)user hammers ^C? Welcome to Security Whack-A-Mole.

@waltinator Aside from adding to /etc/shells, none of these are real problems. There is no reason to disable chsh (as the user will have system access anyway, the security aspect is only to prevent further logins in case the machine is compromised in the future). Ctrl-C will not let you bypass anything, you will just kill the shell prematurely

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
